# Error in removing punctuation: 'float' object has no attribute 'translate'

Tags: string, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to remove punctuations from a col in a data frame by doing the following:

```
def remove_punctuation(text):
      return text.translate(table)

df['data'] = df['data'].map(lambda x: remove_punctuation(x))
```

But I am getting the following error:

> 'float' object has no attribute 'translate'

I checked the dtype of the col as in here:

```
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype
is_string_dtype(df['data'])
```

and got the following output:

> True

I am not sure what's going wrong in here?

I have also tried the following: 
translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)

```
def remove_punctuation(text):
      return text.translate(translator)
df['data'] = df['data'].map(lambda x: remove_punctuation(x))
```

but I am still getting the same error

Comment: convert to str,  df['data']=df['data'].astype(str)

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much

Comment: This error makes me uneasy. Why are you doing this text replacement on _floats_?

Comment: @coldspeed the thing is, it is Not float but it is a string. I posted the code where I checked if it is a string or not and the output was it is indeed a string but I don't know why I was getting this error.

Comment: Your data likely has NaNs. In that case, `.astype(str)` is the WRONG answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your df['data'] has NaN elements.`type(np.nan)` is float. Hence, you are getting an error "'float' object has no attribute 'translate'" while removing punctuations.To fix this issue, you can either

1. Remove NaN elements from df['data'] or,
2. Use `df['data'] = df.fillna({'data':''})` to fill NaN values with empty string.

Once you have taken care of NaN elements in your pandas Series, you can use your map function to remove punctuations.

Hope this helps!